# PostgreSQL - write to inet column using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, mybatis

PostgreSQL has the nifty [inet](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html) type, but there's no corresponding JDBC type for it. How do I store an IP address in an `inet` column using Java?

I'm using [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/), not raw JDBC, but the problem is with JDBC itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered several times on the postgresql mailing list ([2001](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/F142EIo4OUqXIm1AzJX0001a8ac%40hotmail.com), [2015](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BHuS5Hk%3Drxq7do0J9AeTcXkMz2WwU-zHkHK3AKF_7k%2Beg2BxQ%40mail.gmail.com)) as well as several other places.

Since there's no `inet` in JDBC, the easiest solution is pass the IP address in `String` form, then cast to `inet` **in the query itself**.

In mybatis this looks like this:

```
public interface MyMapper {

    @Insert("INSERT INTO my_table (ip) VALUES (#{ip}::INET)")
    int insert(@Param("ip") String ip);

}
```

Another solution is to wrap the address in a custom class, that implements `java.sql.SQLData`, then simply pass your own class as an Object.