# MyBatis support for Postgres network address types?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, mybatis

From what I read from the [docs](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html) it looks like MyBatis doesn't support type handling for [Postgres Network Address](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html) types. It would have been nice if it were a first class JDBC type.

Has anyone tried/written a custom type handler to deal with this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: We may need more info to answer. You should show what you tried (table, class, mapper, type handler, etc.) and how it failed.

Comment: I tested `String` vs. `MACADDR` mapping. Retrieval seems to work out-of-the-box. Setting parameter may require a custom type handler. See the [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-76293824). If you need further help, please update the question to be more specific.

Comment: @ave Thank you for your time & help! I am sorry I didn't add more info specially w.r.t to my knowing that I can definitely use [PGObject](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/util/PGobject.html) & write a custom type handler. I was more interested in knowing/hearing from MyBatis community folks on whether they have any plans to support this natively & from other users on whether they had any problems with using `PGObject`.

Comment: I will add an example of the above & try it out & share here shortly. But please feel free to add your above comment as answer & I will accept it.

Comment: Assuming `String` is used to store these values in your code, I don't see the point in involving `PGObject` in a type handler, but in any case, there won't be 'native support' from MyBatis unless these network types are added to the JDBC API.
In MyBatis users' questions, I rarely see these network address types being used. My guess is that people prefer [casting them in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993413/1261766) rather than writing custom type handler because it's simpler.

Comment: Yesterday night I tested this & got it working fine with `PGObject` & will share it shortly. Postgres JDBC API mentions use of `PGObject` when persisting for "any type that is unknown by JDBC Standards". In fact, that's how Postgres JSON types are being used today & is how it works when using MyBatis aswell. With inline SQL support as you note one can still do with casting at least for this.

Comment: I don't think JDBC API not having a type is a reason for MyBatis not adding native support for it, if so it may not have added [EnumTypeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/EnumTypeHandler.java).